# Sending an image from PHP webservice to mobile client

Tags: php, javascript, json, jquery-mobile

I am returning a JSON object from a PHP webservice handled by a mobile web app (HTML/Javascript client using JQuery mobile). I am planning to send as well an image ; what would be the pros/cons of

- sending the url of the image stored on the server, (displaying `<img src="myserver.com/path/to/myImage.png"></image>`)
- sending the image itself (using base64 encoding for example)?

Comment: don't send the image with php, because that will only add an extra point of failure.  Send the reference of the image to the app and let the app retrieve it directly from the webserver

Comment: - The first solution is the best one (sending the url of the image stored on the server) for execution time and web service responding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst you could send it using base64 encoding, the most effective method would definitely be by **sending the URL of the image stored on the server**, as you initially stated. There are a couple of reasons for this:

1. You can **easily replace the src of an image** already in the DOM, via jQuery or using your own methods.
2. Base64 encoded images, as far as I'm aware, don't work in IE8 or under, so that would be a far less cross-browser compatible way of doing things.

So I'd suggest you **send the URL of the image to the mobile user's browser via AJAX, and place it inside the `src=""` attribute when your user receives it**. This would be the best way to do it and there aren't any downfalls I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Sending the Image URL is always the best option to send the image using j-son specially in the case of web-services,the array which you are returning from you server side script add the image URL in that:

```
"imageurl" => "http://www.example.com//img_png/example.png"
```